# magento jQuery click not working in Firefox & IE

Tags: jquery, magento

I have added custom js in page.xml file.

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/custom_function.js</name>
    <params/>
</action>
```

that js contain code for click:

```
jQuery(".search_img").click(function () {
    var d = jQuery("#search").css("display");
    var value = jQuery("#search").val();
    if (d == "none") {
        jQuery("#search").show();
    }

    if (d == "block") {
        if (value == "") {
            jQuery("#search").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Its working in Chrome and Safari but not working in FF & IE.

Comment: do you see any errors in FF or IE ...?

Answer (score 0):

try this before apply this you have add jquery file  and then write your code in **[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".search_img").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    var d=jQuery("#search").css("display");
    var value=jQuery("#search").val();
    if(jQuery("#search").is(":hidden"))
    {
    jQuery("#search").show();   
    }
    else
    {
        if(value=="")
        {
        jQuery("#search").hide();   
        }
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: my main problem is click is not working.
if i add alert inside click function its not working in FF &IE.
but working nicely in Chrome & safari.

Comment: in console what is coming

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: can you live url or set a fiddle

Comment: Sorry Ruturaj i have solved this problem.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome @dhruv its my pleasure :-)